# cursor: url ( Вращение курсора вокруг своей оси)

Tags: css, css-animation

Я сам дизайнер, и сейчас делаю сайт на конструкторе и могу назначать только стили  CSS

```css
.custom-cursor-section a {
  cursor: url('your-custom-cursor-url-path.png'), auto !important;
}
```

Не могу правильно прописать код или его порядок для вращения курсора вокруг своей оси. На форумах находил куски кода, прописывал, заменял на нужные мне атрибуты и селекторы, но в итоге вокруг себя крутились блоки, ссылки или весь сайт, НО не курсор при ховере.

Вот FAQ сайта, откуда брал код: https://help.semplice.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039805872-Creating-a-custom-cursor

Comment: А если просто анимированную гифку в url загнать?

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за ответ! Да, я думал об этом, но я к этому приду в самую последнюю очередь, если не получится кодом.

Просто хочется понять, какой правильный путь выставить, чтобы именно курсор/картинку крутить, так как потом хочется назначить ей скорость, затухание и так далее.

Comment: Думаю, что никак.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я понял, все равно спасибо! :)

Comment: Можно сделать кодом анимированную веркторную картинку в `svg` и поставить её фоном. Это даже может быть не отдельный файл, а `data-url`. Типа `background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>')`

Comment: @zhurof Хм, звучит как реальный план. Спасибо, я попробую!